# Is there any way to ignore backslashes and forward slashes in link route?

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication, fastify

I am making a user Authentication system and it sends users a confirmation email when user registers, the problem I'm facing is that sometimes link contains / and \ .due to this any text after the / was considered as new route. Is there any way to ignore these slashes. btw I'm using hashing to generate the link.

The link is generated by this piece of code.

```
const hashedEmail = await bcrypt.hash(email,10);
        console.log(await bcrypt.compare(email,hashedEmail))
        const mailOptions = {
            from: 'someone@gmail.com',
            to: email,
            subject: 'Confirm your email',
            text : `Thanks for registering! Please click on the link to confirm your email: 
            http://localhost:3500/confirm/${hashedEmail}`
}
```

confirmation Route

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

// user data: 

const userData = {
    users: require('../model/users.json'),
    setUsersData : function(data) {this.users = data}
}

async function confirmationRoute(fastify,options,done){
    fastify.get('/confirm/:id',async(req,res) => {
        const HashedId = req.params.id;
        let foundUser;
        for (let i = 0; i < userData.users.length; i++) {
            if (await bcrypt.compare(userData.users[i].email,HashedId)){
                foundUser = userData.users[i];
            }
        }
        
        if(foundUser){
            // change isverified to true
            foundUser.isVerified = true;
            // write the new user data to the file
            userData.setUsersData([...userData.users.filter(user => user.email !== foundUser.email),foundUser]);
            await fsPromises.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,'..','model','users.json'),
            JSON.stringify(userData.users)
            );
            res.send({"message":"Account Verified"})
        }
        else{
            res.send({"message":"Invalid Link"})
        }
    })
    done()
}

module.exports = confirmationRoute;
```

Example Link is : http://localhost:3500/confirm/$2b$10$bWUrZ6d0dQuZ8.e/Hqd..OEIaFN2By3nVE6x6H2sHCyLlA/nTriKO

Comment: I think you are looking for `encodeURIComponent(hashedEmail)`

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Yep, I think I have got my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [encode](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/encodeuricomponent) the parameter and [decode](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/decodeuricomponent) it before processing it:

```
const param = encodeURIComponent('hello/world?')
console.log(param)
const data = decodeURIComponent(param)
console.log(data)
```